# Dropbox Webhooks Reliability

Tags: dropbox, webhooks

What kind of guarantees does the Dropbox Webhooks API provide? Is it send once, how many retries, how often?

I'm surprised this isn't addressed AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/webhooks/docs:

> When sending change notifications to your app, Dropbox will handle
>   errors with exponential backoff. Each request that results in a
>   non-200 response code or times out will be re-attempted over the
>   course of about ten minutes. After that, a failure will be reported,
>   which you'll be able to see in the App Console.